# Can I end an activity and start a new one from a fragment switch case?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am working in android studio.I have a  bottom-navigation fragment. For the last switch case, I need a button to navigate to the HomeActivity (home screen). I tried:

...

```
  case SUMMARY:
             navNextText.setText(R.string.end);
             navNextImageView.setOnClickListener(v -> navigateHome());
             navNextText.setOnClickListener(v -> navigateHome());
             break;

        default:
            Log.w(TAG, "Executing a default case in navigateNext(). CTX: " + contextState.toString());
    }

 private void navigateHome() {
    Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).finish();
    Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), HomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(in);
}
```

This works to an extent. I can navigate home, but when I click back into the activity that the navigation fragment resides, the navigation bar resumes where it was previous to changing activity. 
I have also tried adding `onStop()` and `onDestroy` to `private void navigateHome`, but that seemed to do nothing.
I am just wondering what is the cleaner way to close an activity from a fragment and start a new one.

Comment: As @Zain said you have to finish current activity when you leave current activity in order to avoid back to same activity by clicking back button.

Answer (score 0):

just add `finish()` if you want to remove the current activity from the backstack
As you're in a fragment, use `requireActivity().finish()`

Also to make sure you have no activities in back stack, you can remove all using below intent flag

```
 private void navigateHome() {
    Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).finish();
    Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), HomeActivity.class);
    in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); // <<<<< flag
    startActivity(in);
    requireActivity().finish(); // <<< finish the current activity
}
```

Comment: I tried your method and unfortunately got the same result. The bottom navigation resumes where it left off, instead of starting new.